# Creating my own Graph Data Structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I am trying to get my feet wet with Haskell and I have found a few workshop which asks to create a graph data structure. I followed along and created a Binary Tree using map which felt much simpler. I have the following data types given

```hs
type Graph a = [(Node a, Edges)]

type Edges = [NodeID]

type NodeID = Int

data Node a = Node
  { getNodeID :: NodeID,
    getNodeVal :: a
  }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and example node would be as follows

```hs
nodeA = Node 0 'A'
```

and an example graph connected both ways would be

```hs
graphA = [(nodeA, [1]), nodeB, [0]]
```

Now in order to do any kind of insert or remove operation, I would first have to find out what the max NodeID at the moment is. So I am trying to write a maxNodeID as follows

```hs
maxNodeID :: Graph a -> Maybe NodeID
maxNodeID [] = Nothing --base case
```

But I am having a real hard coming up with the next case for this function.

My type definition for insertNode function is as follows

```hs
insertNode :: a -> Graph a -> Graph a
-- This is my idea for a base case but I get a parse error at 0  
insertNode v [] = [a, []] where a = Node {0, v}
```

Any help with this and creating a insertNode function would be much appreciated as it would really help me set myself in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling my own, I would use the [`maximumBy :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> t a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) functrion from Data.List.

```
maxNodeID :: Graph a -> Maybe NodeID
maxNodeID [] = Nothing --base case
maxNodeID xs = Just $ maximumBy (\a b -> compare (getID a) (getID b)) xs
  where getID = getNodeID . fst
```

For your `insertNode` function you need

```
insertNode v [] = [(a, [])] where a = Node 0 v
-- or --
insertNode v [] = [(a, [])] where a = Node {getNodeID = 0, getNodeVal= v}
```

---

Edited to add:

If you are not comfortable with type classes yet, you can read the type of `maximumBy` specialized for Lists as `:: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`.

Comment: could you clarify why use () over {}, even though data types of Node is {}, which looks like a dictionary ds (if thinking in other languages) rather than a tuple. Also I haven't seen Just or maximumBy before will read on that. But would this be achievable using foldr?

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing.  Check Haskell syntax for creating records. (1 of 2)

Comment: `Just` is the other constructor for Maybe.  If one branch is `Nothing` then the other branch has to be `Just (...)`.  Yes it is possible to write using just `foldr` (all the functions of the Foldable class can be) , but why when there is a perfectly good library function already made for you?

Comment: I should have clarified from the start, understanding foldr and map is more important to me atm as they seem to be the building blocks. I need to get practice understanding fundamentals before I start using built in libtaty functions. Hence, this exercise in creating  data structures that I could easily implement in non functional languages. I am trying think about the same problems but in a more functional way.